# Maven Build Works, During Deployment Gets Class Not Found

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

Using Eclipse Mars.2 4.5.2
The Maven build is successful. During deployment I get the following error:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.authy.AuthyApiClient from [Module \"deployment.mavenFlowChartDB5.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}

In the Maven dependency directory I see the related dependency with the class underneath the dependency entry.

Libraries>Maven Dependencies>authy-java-1.1.0.jar>com.auth.AuthyApiCLient

Why doesn't the Deployment see this missing class?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>mavenFlowChartDB5</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>mavenFlowChartDB5</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.2-1002-jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.authy</groupId>
            <artifactId>authy-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org/</url>
            <id>PrimeFaces-maven-lib</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library PrimeFaces-maven-lib</name>
        </repository>
        <repository>  
          <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>  
          <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>  
          <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>  
          <layout>default</layout>  
          <releases>  
            <enabled>true</enabled>  
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>  
          </releases>  
          <snapshots>  
            <enabled>true</enabled>  
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>  
          </snapshots>  
        </repository>  
      </repositories>  
      <pluginRepositories>  
        <pluginRepository>  
          <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>  
          <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>  
          <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>  
          <layout>default</layout>  
          <releases>  
            <enabled>true</enabled>  
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>  
          </releases>  
          <snapshots>  
            <enabled>true</enabled>  
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>  
          </snapshots>  
        </pluginRepository>  
      </pluginRepositories> 
</project>
```

This is the updated pom.xml. I still get the same error. I did notice that the maven-compiler-plugin is repeated a few times. I added this part.

```
<manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Can please you provide your pom.xml?

Comment: Are you deploying from Eclipse? If not then how?

Comment: Yes I am deploying from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are not adding classpath entry in manifest for `mavenFlowChartDB5` war. Could you try adding that using [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-manifest-guide.html) documentation.

Comment: I added the following: <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>